# Image is blurry when show in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsimage

I want to display image in NSTableView, but it seems blurry.

[image]

in another window, I show it using NSButton, then it's OK,

[image]

I tried to scale the image to fit in NSTableView, but it's still blurry, anyone know why?

**[Edit]**
I found a way to resolve it: add a border to NSImageCell, the default border is none. I don't know why.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is not blurry, but washed-out. Looks like a transparency problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem recently too and just found out how to fix it. On my NSTableViewColumn in IB, I use bindings to connect my image to the cell. In the bindings inspector I had "Conditionally Sets Enabled" selected. Turning that off fixed the problem for me.

This image:

[image: Disabled Images]

Became this image:

[image: Enabled Images]

Much better and doesn't look washed out.

Answer (score 0):

The images appear to be in "disabled" state.

How have you created this table column of NSImageCells? You may have "Enabled" unchecked somewhere (the column or its data cell). This should be enabled but not editable (unless you *want* editability).